# Symfony2: phpinfo() using a twig template for layout?

Tags: symfony, twig, php

Twig won't process PHP tags. Hence, it is a challenge to create a `phpinfo()` page based on a layout (say `base.html.twig`).

Is it possible to dump the HTML content of `phpinfo()` into some variable and pass it as body content to the layout? Or, is there a better way to proceed?

Comment: ob_start();
$output = phpinfo();
ob_end_clean();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just capture the output of `phpinfo()` with output buffering, and pass it to the template.

```
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$phpinfo = ob_get_clean();

echo $twig->render('phpinfo.html.twig', array('phpinfo' => $phpinfo));
```

Comment: For styling in your template use <pre><pre> ... if you are using bootstrap add the class prettyprint to the pre

Comment: Don't forget to put a | raw in twig!
`{{ phpinfo | raw }}` to avoid mess in HTML

Answer (score 2):

This is an addition to answer from Federkun.
 In controller:

```
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$phpinfo = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $this->render('phpinfo.html.twig', array(
    'phpinfo'=>$phpinfo,
));
```

Don't forget to put a | raw in twig!

```
{{ phpinfo | raw }}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        ob_start();
        phpinfo();
        $phpinfo = ob_get_clean();

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>'.$phpinfo.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Symfony, if you just need to check `phpinfo()`'s output, you can use `dump(phpinfo())` inside a controller and you'll get the basic `phpinfo()`'s output. Also working to call `phpinfo()` as parameter of the `Response` object then return it:

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
   /**
    * @Route("/", name="default")
    */
   public function index()
   {
       dump(phpinfo());

       // Then return something else, or call directly phpinfo() on return, like bellow
       return new Response(phpinfo());
   }
}
```